# Reload page using different value using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a page which displays All Test Events on default (Initial Page View)

**My controller:**

```
public function testController()
{
   $category = 0; //NEED TO BE CHANGED WHEN USER SELECTED TEST EVENT 2 AND GET ALL EVENTS (Category 2)
   $getEventsBasedOnCategory = //DB QUERY TO GET ALL EVENTS (Category 0)
   //Pass all events to view
}
```

**My HTML page:**

```
<select id = "event_filter">
  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>SELECT Event</option>
  <option value="0">All Test Events</option>
  <option value="2">Test Event 2</option>
</select>
```

**My ajax request:**

```
$("#event_filter").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
           url: '/site/example/displayEvents',
           data: {
               event_filter: $("#event_filter").val()
           },
           async: false,
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(data){

           },
    });
```

});

**My question is how am I going to change the category to 2 (if user selected 2 in select box) and request again from the database and display the events with category 2 on site?**

Im using codeigniter by the way. Thanks

Thanks, Sorry for bothering you guys.

Comment: Can you not access the `event_filter` value in your controller function by doing `$_POST['event_filter']` or something like `$this->input->post('event_filter')`?

Comment: You need to add a controller for your AJAX call that queries the database for events with a category of what ever was selected. Then you need to pass these results back to your jQuery to generate the html for the view. Might just be easier to scrap the AJAX and do a simple POST request to the same controller.

Comment: Hello I want the query to be done on the onchange() event of the select field and not when submitting the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my bad English.

First of all, to retrieve data from **post** in codeigniter use **$this->input->post('event_filter')**.

If you are calling '/site/example/displayEvents', in this function "displayEvents" you have to call the function in the model.

```
public function displayEvents(){
    $data->variableToSend = $this->example_model->events_data($this->input->post('event_filter'));
    $this->load->view('nameOfViewToDisplayData',$data);
}
```

The view is the result in your ajax call, then you can put it in a div.

```
success: function(data){
   $('#target_div').html(data);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using type: POST, this will post it to the next site :-)

The way i understand your question, you need the $category to be equal to the value of your select.

I havent testet you script, but they way you do it:

`$category = 0;
if(isset($_POST['event_filter'])){
$category = $_POST['event_filter'];
}`

and then just a simple

```
"SELECT * FROM {your category} WHERE {your_row_category} = $categori"
```

Comment: Hello what I want is that on the onchange event of select filter it will query again to the DB. I think $_POST[] cannot achieve it